# subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector in the void main c language programming

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, vector, char

I want to add between large numbers, but it gives an error. I am using a char array. There is an error on line 55. [Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>


int chrtoint(char a){
    int i;
    for (i = 48; i<=57; i++)
    if (toascii(i)==a) return i-48;
    return 0;
}

void main(){
    char n1[80];
    char n2[80];

    
    printf("Enter First Number:");
    scanf("%s", &n1);
    printf("\nEnter Second Number:");
    scanf("%s", &n2);
    
    sumNumber(n1 , n2);


}

void sumNumber(char n1 , char n2){
    
    int rs[80];
    int c1, c2;

    int i,j,m, cmax, sum;
    c1 = strlen(n1);
    c2 = strlen(n2);

    strrev(n1);
    strrev(n2);
    
    cmax = c1;
    if(c1<c2){
        cmax = c2;
    }

    m=0;
    for(i=0; i< cmax; i++){
    if(c1==c2 || (i < c1 && i < c2)){
    sum = m+chrtoint(n1[i])+chrtoint(n2[i]); // error is given in this line
    }else if(i >=c1){
    sum = m+chrtoint(n2[i]);
    }else if(i >=c2){
    sum = m+chrtoint(n1[i]);
    }
    rs[i] = sum%10;
    m = sum/10;
    }
    
    if(m){
    rs[i]=m;
    i++;
    }

    printf("\nResult: ");
    for(j=0; j < i; j++){
        printf("%d", rs[i-j-1]);
    }
}
```

I apologize if I have asked the same question. This is the first time I am posting a question on this site. Please tell me if there is something wrong.

Comment: The function argument is `char n1` but you are trying to index it with `n1[i]`.

Comment: I would add use int *n1 or int n1[] in sumNumber declaration.

Comment: The compiler gives a lot of warnings and errors. First thing is to make a prototype (declaration) for function `sumNumber`, because you have a "forward reference" to it. Or move it above `main`.

Comment: Side note: your `chrtoint` function is unnecessarily elaborate.  The conventional way to convert digit characters to numeric digits in C is simply to subtract the constant `'0'` (or, equivalently, `48`) — you don't need that loop or the `toascii` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler should be displaying several warning and error messages.

First, either add a prototype to the function `void sumNumber(char n1, char n2)` or move it above `main`. Speaking of which, your `main` function prototype is not good practice (in some compilers it is illegal); it should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Here:

```
void sumNumber(char n1, char n2)
```

These variables are declared in your main function as arrays of characters so the parameters of `sumNumber` should be either arrays of characters:

```
void sumNumber(char n1[], char n2[])
```

or pointers to characters:

```
void sumNumber(char *n1, char *n2)
```

One more thing, in these lines:

```
 scanf("%s", &n1);
 scanf("%s", &n2);
```

you are passing pointer to an array of 80 characters, which is invalid; it should be

```
scanf("%s", n1);
scanf("%s", n2);
```

Correct these errors and your program should run fine.

Comment: First of all, I tried what you did and the program worked :) Thank you very much. Since I am a newbie in the software industry, I encounter a lot of errors. I hope I can write better codes. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

when we define array of char to be used as string ( we don't scan it with address )
because String in most programing language is already
considered as an address (reference pointer )

Comment: Not helpful. C is a specific programming language and there is no `String` or even `std::string` in C. Even in C++ `std::string` is not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

1-)  I know that there is no String in c.
this why i said ( when we define array of char "to be used as string" )

2-)   according to the point that String is not a reference.  String in all programing language is a non primitive datatype which mean it's variable can be considered an object.
and as we know object is always a reference